# System Resources Exceed Error with BeginTrans and Execute methods

Tags: ms-access

I getting stuck, trying to run a update query (with SQL join 2 tables) through **Begintrans** and **CurrentDB.Execute** method. A "*System Resource Exceed*" error appears afters a few seconds running it.

```
Sub updade_clients()

Dim dbLOCAL_DB As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strWORKSPACE As DAO.WORKSPACE
Set strWORKSPACE = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

strSQL = "" & _
"UPDATE TBL_IND_CLIENTE_2008_01 INNER JOIN TBL_IND_CLIENTE_2011_01 ON " & _
"TBL_IND_CLIENTE_2008_01.NUMERO = TBL_IND_CLIENTE_2011_01.NUMERO SET " & _
"TBL_IND_CLIENTE_2008.01.CONJUNTO_ELETRICO = [TBL_IND_CLIENTE_2011_01]![CONJUNTO];"

strWORKSPACE.BeginTrans
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
DBEngine.CommitTrans

End Sub
```

Both tables have about 1.5 million records.

Answer (score 0):

Means it is running out of memory. 1.5 Million records = headache.